API request is made when copy button is clicked
I have this React template page:
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import FuseSvgIcon from '@fuse/core/FuseSvgIcon';
import format from 'date-fns/format';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/order
import { getRandomBackgroundImage } from '../utils';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { queryAPIKeyByID } from 'app/api/queries/api-keys';
import FuseLoading from '@fuse/core/FuseLoading';

function APIKeyView() {
  const { id: APIKeyID } = useParams();
  const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);
  const { data: apiKeyData, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['APIKeyByID', APIKeyID],
    queryFn: () => queryAPIKeyByID(APIKeyID),
  });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full h-screen">
        <FuseLoading />
      </div>
    );
  }

  const handleCopy = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(apiKeyData.api_token);
    setCopied(true);

    // Reset label back to "Copy" after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => setCopied(false), 2000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        className="relative w-full h-160 sm:h-192 px-32 sm:px-48"
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: 'background.default',
        }}
      >
        <img
          className="absolute inset-0 object-cover w-full h-full"
          src={getRandomBackgroundImage()}
          alt="user background"
        />
      </Box>
      <div className="relative flex flex-col flex-auto items-center p-24 pt-0 sm:p-48 sm:pt-0">
        <div className="w-full max-w-3xl">
          <div className="flex flex-auto items-end">
            <div className="flex items-center ml-auto relative bottom-20">
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                onClick={() => navigate('edit', { state: apiKeyData })}
              >
                <FuseSvgIcon size={20}>heroicons-outline:pencil-alt</FuseSvgIcon>
                <span className="mx-8">Edit</span>
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <Typography className="mt-12 text-4xl font-bold truncate">
            {apiKeyData.username}
          </Typography>

          <Divider className="my-32" />

          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-32">
             
            {apiKeyData.email && (
              <div className="flex items-center gap-24 leading-6">
                <FuseSvgIcon>heroicons-outline:mail</FuseSvgIcon>
                <a
                  className="hover:underline text-primary-500"
                  href={`mailto: ${apiKeyData.email}`}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                >
                  {apiKeyData.email}
                </a>
              </div>
            )}

            {apiKeyData.api_token && (
                <div className="flex items-center gap-24 leading-6">
                  <FuseSvgIcon>heroicons-outline:key</FuseSvgIcon>
                  {`${apiKeyData.api_token.substring(0, 9)  } .... ${  apiKeyData.api_token.substring(apiKeyData.api_token.length - 4)}`}

                  <Button
                      onClick={handleCopy}
                      className="ml"
                  >
                    {copied ? "Copied!" : "Copy"}
                  </Button>
                </div>
            )}
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default APIKeyView;

I added a button to copy the api_key value into clipboard. But when I press the copy button API request is made to get the data again. This action is incorrect. I just need to copy the text. Do you know how I can prevent this?

It seems the unnecessary re-render may happen when the user click the copy button.
Try this code to prevent the unnecessary re-render.
const handleCopy = React.useCallback(() => {
  if (apiKeyData?.api_token) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(apiKeyData.api_token);
    setCopied(true);
    setTimeout(() => setCopied(false), 2000);
  }
}, [apiKeyData]);


I get ERROR Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

The problem is probably caused by a rerender updating the useQuery parameters, storing the parameter as a memo should fix the problem
  const queryParameter = useMemo(() => ({
    queryKey: ['APIKeyByID', APIKeyID],
    queryFn: () => queryAPIKeyByID(APIKeyID),
  }), [APIKeyID]);
  const { data: apiKeyData, isLoading } = useQuery(queryParameter);

This way the query will run once (twice on debug mode) and whenever the value of APIKeyID changes.

For queryFn I get ESLint: Parsing error: Missing semicolon. (24:15)

@PeterPenzov then you can just add the semicolon? it's just linting error, not actual error.

Yes but where exactly I need to add it?

@PeterPenzov There was a typo with the code I posted, the {} of () => {} is considered a function block and not the edges of an object, hence the error, I added brackets around to clarify that it's an object literal.

I tested it but again I get the same problem - API request is made when I click  the button.

You should also make sure that the button has type="button" so that if there is a surrounding it won't submit it and redirect/refresh the page
